# Why is my auto respond code not working?

Tags: php, response, contact-form

I have a contact form that sends me the information that has been submitted. The problem is that it doesn't send an email to the client to confirm the submission. The complete code is listed below. If anyone can tell me what I am missing or what I should change, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Email_Address'])) {

include 'freecontactformsettings.php';

function died($error) {
    echo "Sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

if(!isset($_POST['Full_Name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['Email_Address']) ||
    !isset($_POST['Telephone_Number']) ||
    !isset($_POST['Your_Message']) || 
    !isset($_POST['AntiSpam'])      
    ) {
    died('Sorry, there appears to be a problem with your form submission.');        
}

$full_name = $_POST['Full_Name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['Email_Address']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['Telephone_Number']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['Your_Message']; // required
$antispam = $_POST['AntiSpam']; // required

if (isset($_POST['newsletter'])) {
$newsletter = "yes";
} else {
$newsletter = "no";
}

$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)==0) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($full_name) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'Your Name does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if($antispam <> $antispam_answer) {
$error_message .= 'The Anti-Spam answer you entered is not correct.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\r\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($full_name)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "Newsletter: ".clean_string($newsletter)."\r\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
header("Location: $thankyou");
?>
<script>location.replace('<?php echo $thankyou;?>')</script>


if ($email->send()){ 
$autoemail = new PHPMailer(); 
$autoemail->From = "noreply@altfuels.com"; 
$autoemail->FromName = "Alt Fuels"; 
$autoemail->AddAddress($email_from->Email Address, $full_name->Full Name); 
$autoemail->Subject = "Autorepsonse: We received your submission"; 
$autoemail->Body = "We received your submission. We will contact you soon ...";

$autoemail->Send(); 
}  

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

(*note: I changed some of the newsletter code print a "no" answer to my email.)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and posting the form would be a given.

Comment: at a quick glance, undefined variable. again, show your html form. and this doesn't make sense `if ($newsletter != 'Yes') {
$newsletter != 'No';
}`

Comment: and now you have a magic answer. ask them, I'm out.

Comment: Do you want to see the whole html code, or just the part that is about the newsletter? That part works. I tried it before I put the auto-respond code in.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referencing `$thankyou` which is undefined, unless it was defined in `freecontactformsettings.php` which you have not listed.

Comment: Yes, it is defined in freecontactformsettings.php, and it redirects to a thankyou.htm file. It too works! I got everything working and then put in the auto-respond code. It sends me the information, but does not send the auto reply to the client.